# Python Use of File = defined variable

Tags: python, file, version

I am attempting to output a file that was read and altered.

```
new_file = open("MC_QS_MODIFIED.inp","w")
...
...
print( final_data , file=new_file )
new_file.close()
```

and python is taking exception to the = in `print(final_data, file=new_file )`

It worked at home but now that I am attempting to run the script at work, Python 2.7.6 is giving me a syntax error. I am still pretty new to this, so I don't know if my code is 3.0+ and 2.7.6 doesn't like it or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `print()` is not a function but [a statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), unless you tell Python you want to use the Python 3 syntax.

Put this at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to *disable* the `print` statement in the compiler so you can use the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) instead.

You may run into other problems if you developed on Python 3 and try to run on Python 2, however.

Comment: You are correct. I added `from __future__ import print_function` and it is giving me grief that "'list' object has no attribute 'clear'" I will see if I can't install 3.0+ on the computer here rather than going through this line by line.  Thank you very much Martijn

Comment: @CharlesButler: `list.clear` doesn't exist in Python 3 either; not sure where you got yourself a list where Python 3 would return a dictionary or set instead. :-)